# azure pipelines : accessing secret variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to access secret variable to pass it to another script.

I expect following code in pipeline to print Value but it prints some text 'xxx' ragardless of the value of a secret variable

```
echo xxx
```

Pipeline Snippet

```
steps:
  - bash: echo This script could use $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to access a secret variable, you could print it to a file. Check the example below:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $env:var1 | Out-File C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Newfolder\debug.txt


  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    var1: $(System.AccessToken)
```

But `System.Accesstoken` is a PAT token generated for the service identity “Project Collection Build Service (account)”, it's not needed to verify the value of `System.AccessToken`. In addition, if you want to print the value of `System.AccessToken` to a file, you need to check the `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` in the agent job:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Azure pipelines will scan the output and mask the secret, you can simply split it up and print it in two parts.
Here is a bash example:

```bash
  echo "${MY_SECRET:0:10}" # Print the first 10 characters
  echo "${MY_SECRET:10:100}" # Print character 11 - 100
```

You should of course only do it for debugging purposes and not leave it in your pipeline.

Comment: One-liner: `echo "MY_SECRET: ${MY_SECRET:0:1} ${MY_SECRET:1:100}"`
The answer would still be masked if the secret was shorter than 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Updates:

If I save secret value to a file and publish that file as an artifact secret is visible in cleartext.

After speaking to my colleagues I have realized that all text in logs if it contains a secret value it will be masked.

It will interesting to see if I have 2 variables viz.

```
OPEN_VAR='something' # No Secret
```

and

```
SECRET_VAR='something' # Values same as above but Secret
```

if I print $OPEN_VAR ;  does it mask value because "something" is also a value of "SECRET_VAR"

Comment: Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

Answer (score 1):

This is because `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` is a secret. If you do the same with variable which is not a secret you will be able to see value.

Comment: how do I verfiy if my script is getting correct value

Comment: @forvaidya use it in the scrip :).

Comment: Please check this [topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/618929/what-is-the-scope-of-the-token-in-systemaccesstoke.html). `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` is a PAT token generated by AzDO. You can be sure that this is a valid. User linked to this token can have not enough permission (please check here https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2018/12/04/authenticate-azure-devops-against-its-own-rest-api/), or you may use it in a wrong way, but you can be sure that it has a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell solution, since the above bash solution didn't work for me:

```yaml
# DEBUG: print access token for local debugging
- powershell: Write-Host ($env:var1).substring(0,1) + ($env:var1).substring(1)
  displayName: DEBUG - print access token for local debugging
  env:
    var1: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Obviously don't use this in production code.  I used it to get the System Access Token so I could do local debugging in Postman instead of pushing commits and running my pipeline every time.